# How to use RTC Wake Up and alarm Intent

Tags: java, android, alarm, android-alarms

I'm working on a project, my goal is to configurate a cell phone. I have to **related the sounds of the phone with a calendar**.

The user can choose the day, the beginning hour and the ending hour and, the configuration parameters of the sound. ***An example, every monday, the application has to put the phone in silence mode, between 8 am and 4 pm***.

I already have all the parameters, all I have to do now, is to apply them. To do so, I think the use of `RTC Wake Up` is the best.

Here's the **code that i'm working on** :

```
TimePicker hourBeginning = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.hourBeginningTimePicker);
TimePicker hourEnding = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.hourEndingTimePicker);
SeekBar volumePhone = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volumePhoneOptionSeekBar);
SeekBar volumeAlarm = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volumeAlarmOptionSeekBar);
SeekBar volumeApplication = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volumeApplicationOptionSeekBar);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, heureBeginning.getCurrentHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, heureEnding.getCurrentMinute());


// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

I don't understand how this works, and **how it suppose to solve my problem** :

```
// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

If you think, there's a better solution, or know how to use correctly `RTC Wake Up` to solve my problem, help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alarm manager to trigger the alarm at a specific defined time.

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            xyz.class);

    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent
            .getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Yes, this can works, and you need to create a new class of course